# How to Autowire generic class using Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, generics, inversion-of-control, spring-4

I have class like below :

```
class Foo<KeyType, ValueType> {
    private Producer<KeyType, ValueType> kafkaProducer;

    public Foo() {
        this.kafkaProducer = new Producer<KeyType, ValueType>(new ProducerConfig());
    }
}
```

There is another DAO class which uses this Foo class which looks like below :

```
class CompanyDao {
    @Autowired
    private Foo<String, Integer> fooHelper;
}
```

I want Spring to inject object of type `Foo` in `fooHelpder` object. For this I am using following XML configuration :

```
<bean id="fooHelper" class="com.ask.util.Foo">
    <property name="KeyType" value="java.lang.String" />
    <property name="ValueType" value="Integer" />
</bean>
<bean id="CompanyDao" class="com.ask.dao.CompanyDao">
    <property name="fooHelper"><ref bean="fooHelder"/></property>
</bean>
```

When I use this XML configurtion, Spring throws following error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fooHelper' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'KeyType' of bean class [com.ask.util.fooHelper]: Bean property 'KeyType' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
```

Any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you show your getter and setter-methods?

Comment: Just remove both properties `KeyType` and `ValueType`: `<bean id="fooHelper" class="com.ask.util.Foo" />`

Comment: @Tunaki, thaks. After removing both properties, it worked.

Comment: By the way: KeyType, ValueType are type arguments of your class. Properties (as used in Spring) are fields (or setter) like fooHelper in CompanyDao. So type arguments != properties. This is the reason why it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two changes needed.

First one because Spring 4 is now using Generics during injection (Pre Spring 4 version ignored generics):

```
class CompanyDao {
    private Foo<KeyType, ValueType> fooHelper;
}
```

(annotation is not needed when you are using XML config)

and

```
<bean id="fooHelper" class="com.ask.util.Foo">
</bean>
<bean id="CompanyDao" class="com.ask.dao.CompanyDao">
    <property name="fooHelper"><ref bean="fooHelder"/></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add KeyType and ValueType attributes to your class with setter methods.

Comment: Which class? CompanyDao class or Foo class?

Comment: Actually your Foo class would be modified to `Foo<String, Integer>` and will have KeyType and ValueType as attributes.